# React/Tailwind CSS: Search bar filter moving when typed in/filtering data

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Its been a while since I coded in react and I'm working on teaching myself again. Also this is the first time I've used Tailwind CSS. I'm working with a navbar component that has a search bar to filter data within a database. I have everything setup correctly for the most part. The issue is that when you type in the search bar, the user img, and buttons moved like the nav sections is being pushed down when the filter response shows up below the search bar.

Here is my code for the navbar with the search bar

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import UserDropdown from "../../components/Dropdowns/UserDropdown.js";
import AccountDropdown from "../Dropdowns/AccountDropdown.js";

export default function Navbar({ data }) {
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
  const [wordEntered, setWordEntered] = useState("");

  const handleFilter = (event) => {
    const searchWord = event.target.value;
    setWordEntered(searchWord);
    const newFilter = data.filter((value) => {
      return value.dealership.toLowerCase().includes(searchWord.toLowerCase());
    });

    if (searchWord === "") {
      setFilteredData([]);
    } else {
      setFilteredData(newFilter);
    }
  };


  return (
    <>
      {/* Navbar */} 
      <div className="relative bg-lightBlue-600 md:pt-32 pb-32 pt-12">
        <nav className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full z-10 bg-transparent md:flex-row md:flex-nowrap md:justify-start flex items-center p-4">
          <div className="w-full mx-autp items-center flex justify-between md:flex-nowrap flex-wrap md:px-10 px-4">
            {/* Brand */}
            <a
              className="text-white text-sm uppercase hidden lg:inline-block font-semibold"
              href="#pablo"
              onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
            >
              Dashboard
            </a>
            <div className="md:flex flex-row flex-wrap items-center lg:ml-auto mr-3">
              <AccountDropdown />
            </div>
            {/* Form */}
            <form className="md:flex hidden flex-row flex-wrap items-center lg:ml-auto mr-3">
              <div className="relative flex w-full flex-wrap items-stretch">
                <span className="z-10 h-full leading-snug font-normal absolute text-center text-blueGray-300 absolute bg-transparent rounded text-base items-center justify-center w-8 pl-3 py-3">
                  <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
                </span>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Search here..."
                  className="border-0 px-3 py-3 placeholder-blueGray-300 text-blueGray-600 relative bg-white bg-white rounded text-sm shadow outline-none focus:outline-none focus:ring w-full pl-10" 
                  value={wordEntered} 
                  onChange={handleFilter}
                />
              </div>
              {filteredData.length != 0 && (
              <div className="dataResult">
              {filteredData.slice(0, 15).map((value) => {
            return (
              <a className="dataItem" href="/admin/dashboard">
                <p>{value.dealership}</p>
              </a>
            );
          })}
              </div>
              )}
            </form>
            {/* User */}
            <ul className="flex-col md:flex-row list-none items-center hidden md:flex">
              <UserDropdown />
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      {/* End Navbar */}
    </>
  );
}
```

Here are a few pics of what it does.

[image: Before Typing]

[image: After Typing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is because of `align-items` property. When the data shows,  the height of the component is changing so alignment should be `flex-start` in css. You can remove items-center because its default value is `flex-start` in css. Or you can replace with `items-start`.
You wrote

```
<nav className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full z-10 bg-transparent md:flex-row md:flex-nowrap md:justify-start flex items-center p-4">
```

And I think it should be like this

```
<nav className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full z-10 bg-transparent md:flex-row md:flex-nowrap md:justify-start flex items-start p-4">
```

Or this

```
<nav className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full z-10 bg-transparent md:flex-row md:flex-nowrap md:justify-start flex p-4">
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried both of these suggestions but it doesn't appear to change anything.

Comment: I think it causes from the data list component if you can make the list component absolute then its height cannot change the height of the parent.

Comment: Okay so that worked, so adding absolute to the data list component keeps it in place. Except now the response area that filters shows up over top of the search bar when typing.

Comment: I got it to work, just had to change up some of the flex items and adjust the top margin a bit. Thank you @yusuf_sabri !

Comment: You are welcome. Happy to hear that. Also, you should add relative to the parent of the data list so data list position will be according to the parent instead of the whole screen.